# Cobol call Stored Procedure - SQLCODE -440

Tags: db2, cobol, db2-zos

I am using DB2 12 (Z/OS).
I have a cobol Db2 program (name: TESTSS)
This program calls an SQL Stored Prodecure (SP_TEST1)
The Stored Procedure is defined on the STXXAA scheme.

During BIND I get the sqlcode -440.

BIND command (the job that performs the binding is executed with the DB2C user (Master DB))

```
DSN S(A4KK)                                                  
BIND PACKAGE(CCA4PBT) OWNER(DB2C) QUALIFIER(CA4FX) -        
  MEMBER(TESTSS) CURRENTDATA(NO) DEGREE(1) -                 
  DYNAMICRULES(BIND) EXPLAIN(YES) ISOLATION(CS) -            
  RELEASE(COMMIT) VALIDATE(BIND) PATH('DB2C')                
RUN PROGRAM(DSNTIAD) PLAN(DSNTIAD)                          
END
```

Error

```
$TEP002I STEPLIB Activated                           
$TEP006I STEPLIB Dataset List - DDName($TEP0001):    
$TEP007I - SYS4.DB2.VCR1M0A.SDSNEXIT                 
$TEP007I - SYS2.DB2.VC.TSETA2.SDSNLOAD               
DSNX200I  +A4KK BIND SQL ERROR                       
           USING DB2C AUTHORITY                      
           PLAN=(NOT APPLICABLE)                     
           DBRM=TESTSS                               
           STATEMENT=1746                            
           SQLCODE=-440                              
           SQLSTATE=42884                            
           TOKENS=PROCEDURE.SP_TEST1             
           CSECT NAME=DSNXOSTP                       
           RDS CODE=1277956                          
DSNT233I  +A4KK UNSUCCESSFUL BIND FOR                
           PACKAGE =                                 
LOA4KK.CCA4PBT.TESTSS.(2021-05-28-07.45.02.577283)
```

Why is Stored searched on the PROCEDURE schema? I specified the PATH(DB2C) parameter in BIND.
I would have expected the DB2C schema to be used to qualify the stored procedure.

The binding would have gone into error anyway because the Stored is defined on another scheme. But I would have asked the DBAs to modify the PATH parameter to add the STXXAA schema.

Where am I wrong?

---

***EDIT 01/07/2021***  Change Approach to the problem.

The customer does not want to change the "PATH" bind parameter.
So I changed the "VALIDATE" bind parameter to "RUN".
Later I modified the program and at the beginning I put "SET CURRENT PATH = CURRENT PATH, "STXXAA" "

At runtime, the call to the Stored Procedure is failed (SQLCODE -440).
The DBAs have assured me they have set GRANT EXECUTE PUBLIC.

Here is an excerpt from the ***cobol*** program.

```
       01 VARIABLES.
          03 WS-SQLCODE                 PIC S9(04).
          03 WS-STMSQL.
                49 WS-STMSQL-L            PIC S9(004) COMP.
                49 WS-STMSQL-T            PIC  X(500).
           03 WS-STMPATH.
                49 WS-STMPATH-L            PIC S9(004) COMP.
                49 WS-STMPATH-T            PIC  X(2048).
      *
           03 WS-QUALIFIER-TEMP           PIC X(50).
      *    
           03 WSP-P1              PIC X(02).
           03 WSP-P2.
              49 WSP-P2-L         PIC S9(004) COMP.
              49 WSP-P2-T         PIC  X(50).
           03 WSP-P3.
              49 WSP-P3-L         PIC S9(004) COMP.
              49 WSP-P3-T         PIC  X(50).
           03 WSP-P4.
              49 WSP-P4-L    PIC S9(004) COMP.
              49 WSP-P4-T    PIC  X(3926).
      *
           MOVE  '"STXXAA"'           TO WS-QUALIFIER-TEMP
      *
           MOVE 50                    TO WS-STMSQL-L
           STRING 'SET CURRENT PATH = CURRENT PATH, WS-QUALIFIER-TEMP
             DELIMITED BY SIZE        INTO WS-STMSQL-T.
      *
           EXEC SQL
             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
                :WS-STMSQL
           END-EXEC.
      *
           MOVE SQLCODE                     TO SEA-SQLCODE
           PERFORM A9999-CTRL-ERROR.
 
           EXEC SQL
             SELECT CURRENT PATH
               INTO :WS-STMPATH
               FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
           END-EXEC.
      *
           DISPLAY 'WS-STMPATH...' WS-STMPATH 
      *
           MOVE SQLCODE                     TO SEA-SQLCODE
           PERFORM A9999-CTRL-ERROR.
      *
           MOVE '04'                       TO WSP-P1
           MOVE 6                          TO WSP-P2-L
           MOVE 'TESTSP'                   TO WSP-P2-T
           MOVE 24                         TO WSP-P3-L
           MOVE 'TEST CALL BATCH 01-07-21' TO WSP-P3-T
           MOVE 04                         TO WSP-P4-L
           MOVE 'TEST'                     TO WSP-P4-T
      *
           EXEC SQL
              CALL SP_WRITE_LOG
                  (
                   :WSP-P1
                  ,:WSP-P2
                  ,:WSP-P3
                  ,:WSP-P4
                  )
           END-EXEC.
      *
           MOVE SQLCODE                     TO SEA-SQLCODE
           PERFORM A9999-CTRL-ERROR.
```

***Stored Procedure***

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE STXXAA.SP_TEST1 (
     IN P1          CHAR(2)
    ,IN P2          VARCHAR(50)
    ,IN P3          VARCHAR(50)
    ,IN P4          VARCHAR(3926)
    ) VERSION V1
    LANGUAGE SQL
    WLM ENVIRONMENT FOR DEBUG MODE XXYY
    ALLOW DEBUG MODE
    QUALIFIER STXXAA
    AUTONOMOUS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ...
    COMMIT;
END
```

***Error***

```
DSNT408I SQLCODE = -440, ERROR:  NO AUTHORIZED PROCEDURE NAMED SP_TEST1   
          HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND                                
DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 42884 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE                              
DSNT415I SQLERRP    = DSNXOSTP SQL PROCEDURE DETECTING ERROR                  
DSNT416I SQLERRD    = 229380  0  0  -1  0  0 SQL DIAGNOSTIC INFORMATION       
DSNT416I SQLERRD    = X'00038004'  X'00000000'  X'00000000'  X'FFFFFFFF'      
          X'00000000'  X'00000000' SQL DIAGNOSTIC INFORMATION                  
BOTTOM OF LIST ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

***Sysout - Display "WS-STMPATH"***

```
WS-STMPATH..."DB2C","STXXAA"
```

If (without modifying the program) I use the qualifier the call statement it works fine.

*example*

```sql
           EXEC SQL
              CALL STXXAA.SP_WRITE_LOG
                  (
                   :WSP-P1
                  ,:WSP-P2
                  ,:WSP-P3
                  ,:WSP-P4
                  )
           END-EXEC.
```

Have you got any advice?

Thanks,

Comment: Try  `PATH('DB2C', 'STXXAA')`

Comment: I agree with you. But then shouldn't the TOKEN returned on the error be DB2C.SP_TEST1?

Comment: Cannot comment on that,  maybe unwise to make assumptions.

Comment: The customer does not want to change the "PATH" bind parameter.
So I changed the "VALIDATE" bind parameter to "RUN".
Later I modified the program and at the beginning I put "SET CURRENT PATH = CURRENT PATH, "STXXAA" "
At runtime, the call to the Stored Procedure is failed (SQLCODE -440).
The DBAs have assured me they have set GRANT EXECUTE PUBLIC.
Have you got any advice?

Comment: The customer DBA folks will have solutions for this common requirement to be able to call stored procedures with unqualified names, and also a convention for OWNER for stored procedures. If PATH('DB2C', 'STXXAA') is not acceptable for bind, is PATH(USER,...) acceptable? Have a conversation with the customer DBAs to find how they do things at their site. Also try `SET CURRENT PATH = CURRENT PATH, USER` .

Comment: Hi mao, also tried with "USER" but I don't think it works. Unfortunately, DBAs are not collaborative. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Keep in mind that the reserved word USER must not be quoted when used in the PATH bind option.  A good relationship with DBAs is a pre-req for any successful rollout, but that is not a matter for stackoverflow.